# Coinbase API keys required for non-auth endpoints?

Tags: coinbase-api

Using the coinbase API (in Python) to try and get price information for currency pairs. supposedly this endpoint does not require authentication and sure you can get the information from a http request. But if you want to use the Client from coinbase.wallet.client as in the examples, you are forced to provide API keys.
1. Is there another class that can be used to retrieve price data without providing API keys?
2. If you must create an API key for your account, what is the absolute minimum permissions you need to enable on the API key to allow getting price data for currency pairs

Answer (score 0):

For data endpoints in the API, not requiring auth, turns out you can simply pass any string as the api key and the request will succeed.